# messed up lua paths after trying to set up debugging

Tags: debugging, lua, zerobrane

I would like to debug my way through a large lua codebase. To do this, I downloaded ZeroBrane and followed their instructions to set up the bundled mobdebug.

The codebase is koreader. The following shellscript reproduces what I've done:

```
# dependencies for building koreader
sudo apt-get install build-essential git patch wget unzip \
gettext autoconf automake cmake libtool nasm luarocks libsdl2-dev \
libssl-dev libffi-dev libsdl2-dev libc6-dev-i386 xutils-dev linux-libc-dev:i386 zlib1g:i386

# get the source
git clone https://github.com/koreader/koreader.git
cd koreader && ./kodev fetch-thirdparty

# build it, this will take a long time
./kodev build

# assuming you have ZeroBrane installed
export ZBS=/opt/zbstudio
export LUA_PATH="./?.lua;$ZBS/lualibs/?/?.lua;$ZBS/lualibs/?.lua"
export LUA_CPATH="$ZBS/bin/linux/x86/?.so;$ZBS/bin/linux/x86/clibs/?.so"

# execute it, this will run lua
./kodev run
```

Executing `./kodev run` leads to the following error message:

```
 [*] Current time: 10/14/19-17:55:34
./luajit: ./datastorage.lua:3: module 'libs/libkoreader-lfs' not found:
    no field package.preload['libs/libkoreader-lfs']
    no file './libs/libkoreader-lfs.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/lualibs/libs/libkoreader-lfs/libs/libkoreader-lfs.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/lualibs/libs/libkoreader-lfs.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x86/libs/libkoreader-lfs.so'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x86/clibs/libs/libkoreader-lfs.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./datastorage.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./reader.lua:18: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x55a81bf25771
~/programming/koreader
```

If there are no definitions of `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH`, there are no problems and koreader runs just fine. So I assume that the import paths are somehow broken. How do I set this up correctly?

Maybe this helps you, if I read the code correctly, `./kodev run` will (at some point) execute this:

```
-- set search path for 'require()'
package.path =
    "common/?.lua;rocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;frontend/?.lua;" ..
    package.path
package.cpath =
    "common/?.so;common/?.dll;/usr/lib/lua/?.so;rocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;" ..
    package.cpath
```

The actual location of libkoreader-lfs.so is:

```
/home/lklein/programming/koreader/base/build/x86_64-linux-gnu-debug/libs/libkoreader-lfs.so
```

Indeed, if I append this to the CPATH with

```
/home/lklein/programming/koreader/base/build/x86_64-linux-gnu-debug/?.so
```

then it can run. What is lua doing here? Is it always assuming some default LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH if none are set? Because it works just fine without me specifying any path.

Comment: It really takes long to build. I've waited like 20 minutes to verify it already: add `./?.so` to `LUA_CPATH`, it seems that run script changes directory to `base/build/...` and that's the only meaningful difference between your path and default one. I'll leave an answer once I can verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values for both paths are located in [luaconf.h#LUA_PATH_DEFAULT](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html#LUA_PATH_DEFAULT) ff. (5.3).

That being said - your `LUA_CPATH` misses two things from the default one: `LUA_CDIR/loadall.so` and `./?.so`. In your case the problem is due to lack of the second one.

That is because the `./kodev run` do some additional actions to set-up runtime environment. At some point the working directory is changed to `EMU_DIR` (e.g. `./koreader-emulator-x86_64-linux-gnu-debug/koreader`). This very directory also has a valid `libs/libkoreader-lfs.so`.

Change `LUA_CPATH` to contain `./?.so`:

```
export LUA_CPATH="$ZBS/bin/linux/x86/?.so;$ZBS/bin/linux/x86/clibs/?.so;./?.so"
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. (extra thanks for actually building the repo. It takes indeed very long :D)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to load library `libkoreader-lfs`, which is not found in any of the paths set up in `LUA_CPATH` or `LUA_PATH`. I don't know your project structure to give you the exact answer, but since it works when you *don't* set up those environment variables and doesn't work when you do, it looks like you are overwriting some default values for those variables.

Try *adding* to those variables instead of *setting* them:

```
export LUA_PATH="$LUA_PATH;./?.lua;$ZBS/lualibs/?/?.lua;$ZBS/lualibs/?.lua"
export LUA_CPATH="$LUA_CPATH;$ZBS/bin/linux/x86/?.so;$ZBS/bin/linux/x86/clibs/?.so"
```

Comment: I tried that, too. But it makes no difference. In fact, LUA_PATH doesn't exist before the script is executed. I think it's something lua specific.

Comment: You are not showing the entire script you are running. For example, your `package.cpath` includes `common/?.so` and `common?.dll` paths, but none of them are shown in the error message. Can you show the *entire* script that only includes setting path/cpath and `require` command that fails? Also, what is the actual location of the module you are trying to load relative to the script you are running?

Comment: This is a huge existing codebase, not just one script. It's not clear to me what's executed when. The code is here https://github.com/koreader/koreader maybe the structure makes sense to a lua pro. But I can't just give you the relevant snippets. I don't know which ones that would be.